# Http Basic authentication using Spring Security with Angular 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, angular6, angular-http-interceptors

I am developing a Angular 6 application for which I am using Spring Boot for REST services And using Spring security Basic authentication for authorization purpose.

The issue is , basic authentication is not working and it shows pop up everytime i login into the application. I am using  interceptor in angular 6 for adding the authorization header.

Can anybody please help as to where I am going wrong ?

Code :

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
        let username=localStorage.getItem("username")
        let password=localStorage.getItem("password")
        const customReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username+":"+password) )
        });
        return next.handle(customReq);
    }

    constructor() { }
}
```

And the spring boot code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/home/**", "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().httpBasic();

    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
}
```

Since I am new to Spring please let me know if you need any other files.

Comment: Change log level of Security and you can see who and why was decline you request. Add to the properties: `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`

Comment: I tried doing that and it showed the error as 
`Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point`

Comment: not sure, try without password encoding. Otherwise try to debug or add additional logs to the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` , especially method **authenticate**. Maybe some problem with SELECT in Database

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when you **@SpringBootApplication** class is in one package and your **SecurityConfig** class is not present in sub package.

For example, if Application is in `com.example.app` package and your security config is in `com.security.example` then Spring cannot find your configuration and goes ahead with Spring security defaults like form based login page.

Please check the package structure and add **@ComponentScan** if requried.

Comment: Thanks! I checked and the classes are in the same package/ subpackage also I tried adding **@ComponentScan** but no luck.